# Getting error /WEB-INF/jsf/viewlogin.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource while inetgrating spring 4.2.3 and JSF2.2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, jsf-2.2, spring-faces

I am trying to integrate facelets with my Spring. I tried the folowing configuration but getting following error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springWebDispatcher] in context with path [/LS360ProxyAPIWeb] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.faces.FacesException: /WEB-INF/jsf/viewlogin.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource] with root cause
com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/jsf/viewlogin.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
```

Here what I did. First I added following maven dependencies to my project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I added following lines in my startup

```
@Order(1)
public class FrameworkBootstrap implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        container.getServletRegistration("default").addMapping("/resource/*");
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootContextConfiguration.class);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        container.addListener(new RequestContextListener());

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.register(WebServletContextConfiguration.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("springWebDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(null, 20_971_520L, 41_943_040L, 512_000));
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        container.setInitParameter("javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX", ".xhtml");
        container.getServletRegistration("FacesServlet").addMapping("*.xhtml");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext restContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ....
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext soapContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ...

    }  
}
```

In my WebServletContextConfiguration class I added the following view Resolver

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(
    basePackageClasses = {WebControllerMarker.class},
    useDefaultFilters = false,
    includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(WebController.class)
)
public class WebServletContextConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ....
    /**
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {    
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
     */
    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver faceletViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JsfView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsf/view");
        resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
        return resolver;
    }
    ....

}
```

I uncommented my JSP view. JSP view works fine when application runs. I also have spring security In my rootcontext.

```
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@ComponentScan(..)
@Import({SecurityConfiguration.class, ...})
public class RootContextConfiguration {
    ....
}
```

Spring Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
prePostEnabled = true, 
order = 0, 
mode = AdviceMode.PROXY,
proxyTargetClass = false
)
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {FilterMarker.class})
    @Order(1)
    public static class RestApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        ....
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity security) {
            security.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
            security
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/sso/cas/lf/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")

                // Any request simply requires authentication, regardless of permissions.
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check" )
                    .failureUrl("/login?loginFailed")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/interceptor.do")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?loggedOut")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionFixation()
                    .changeSessionId()
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                    .sessionRegistry(this.sessionRegistryImpl())
                .and()
            .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
        }
}
```

I added following faces-config.xml in my WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

I added following login.xhtml page in my WEB-INF/jsf/view/login.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>JSF Spring  Integration Example</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>Item Master</h3>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Then I ran my project but getting error. What I am doing wrong and what I am missing ?

Thanks

Comment: The error says `/WEB-INF/jsf/viewlogin.xhtml` file does not exist. How exactly is that unclear? Make sure the file exists, or fix the prefix path to include a trailing slash in case you actually intented to locate `/WEB-INF/jsf/view/login.xhtml`

Comment: Ah ... What a miss ... ypu `resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsf/view/");` works. Give your answer so I can accept it. Just one question did I integrate it right ? I mean everything I did it's ok or there is any other thing that I need to consider while integrating facelets with spring ? Thanks

Comment: I don't do Spring. I only do Java EE.

Comment: :-D. cool. give answer. I will accept it :-)